# Whether the Apache FTPClient.retrieveFile method creates temporary file

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using Apache `FTPClient` for the Android. I download files from the server and overwrite them instead of local ones. I need to make sure that the files were downloaded correctly. Will the method `FTPClient.retrieveFile` work for me? Does it check the correctness of the file or just overwrite it immediately? I. e. if the broken file was downloaded (for example the Internet disconnect), then on the local device I will receive old version of the file or broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons Net [`FTPClient.retrieveFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFile(java.lang.String,java.io.OutputStream)) does not work with any local files directly. It takes [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) as a parameter and blindly writes the downloaded data to it.

It is up to the `OutputStream`, what it does with the data.

If you use [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), it will overwrite the existing file *immediately* – even *before* you actually call `FTPClient.retrieveFile`.

If you need any other behavior, you have to code it.